# Where did dragons come from in Middle-Earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, dragons

All that I know of Smaug is that he (she?) came out of nowhere to attack and conquer Erebor. Where exactly did he come from? In fact, what are the origins of dragons? Did Ilúvatar create them or did they come from somewhere else?

Answer (score 34):

Dragons can't be corrupted Eagles because the first one was wingless.

If they were Maiar we would surely expect to see them mentioned in the Valaquenta, but yet they're not.

We do, in actual fact, have one recorded description of Morgoth "creating" a being in the Silmarillion: the description of the origin of the wolf Carcharoth in Of Beren and Luthien:

> he chose one from among the whelps of the race of Draugluin; and he fed him with his own hand upon living flesh, and put his power upon him. Swiftly the wolf grew, until he could creep into no den, but lay huge and hungry before the feet of Morgoth. There the fire and anguish of hell entered into him, and **he became filled with a devouring spirit**, tormented, terrible, and strong

Furthermore, this wasn't some simple dumb beast:

> Now Carcharoth espied them from afar, and he was filled with doubt; for news had long been brought to Angband that Draugluin was dead. Therefore when they approached he denied them entry, and **bade them stand**

(My emphasis in both cases).

It doesn't, and shouldn't, boggle the mind too much to imagine Glaurung having a similar origin, though from a snake or lizard rather than a wolf pup.

As for what kind of spirit this could be, an easy answer is provided by the Silmarillion, chapter 2 (Of Aule and Yavanna):

> Behold! When the Children awake, then the thought of Yavanna will awake also, and it will summon spirits from afar, and they will go among the kelvar and the olvar, and some will dwell therein, and be held in reverence, and their just anger shall be feared.

There's absolutely nothing in Tolkien that dictates that the Ainur (Valar and Maiar) were the *only* spirits in Middle-earth, and this third class of spirit provides an answer for a lot of other beings too.

---

**Update - 13th March 2015**

In Christopher Tolkien's commentary on paragraph 307 of the *Grey Annals* (History of Middle-earth 11) he notes the following (with my emphasis):

> ...the manuscript reads 'the fell spirit of Morgoth, who made him' (cf.IV.128).  My father underlined the last three words in pencil, and faintly and barely legibly at the foot of the page he noted : '**Glaurung must be a demon [??contained in worm form]**.'

This is the sole statement I am aware of that establishes a definite origin for dragons (aside from works such as the *Lost Tales* where they are artificial constructs) and it supports my supposition that dragons may have had a similar origin to the wolf Carcharoth.

Comment: In relation to my final paragraph, see the Valaquenta: "in majesty they are peers, surpassing beyond compare all others, whether of the Valar and the Maiar, or of **any other order** that Iluvatar has sent into Ea" (my emphasis).

Comment: Clarifying that "my last paragraph" in my previous comment refers to this answer as it stood before my update of 13th March 2015.

Comment: Doesn't the quote in your update support the "another kind of spirit" theory?  If Glaurung was simply an animal twisted into a colossal monster (like Carcharoth), he wouldn't be a "demon" and he wouldn't be "contained" in any form.  That sounds like a Balrog-type creature, a supernatural force embodied in flesh, likely a non-Ainur spirit as you alluded to in the final paragraph and first comment of your pre-update answer.

Comment: @Nerrolken - that's exactly what I'm saying.  Note that the text says of Carcharoth: "he became filled with a devouring spirit" (i.e Carcharoth was **not** "simply an animal twisted into a colossal monster"; the text also establishes that Carcharoth was even able to speak; see earlier in my answer), so hence it supports a similar origin.  Carcharoth was a demon contained in wolf form, Glaurung a demon contained in worm form.

Comment: Are we to take that quote as a literal "spirit", as in a supernatural being?  I took it to mean a "spirit" in the sense of personality or state of mind: Carcharoth was "filled with an all-consuming hunger" or "filled with a great rage," etc.  Like saying Bruce Wayne was "driven by a spirit of vengeance."  In a world where Elves can "wake up trees" and teach them to speak, the story of Carcharoth seemed to be a similar sort of thing, not a form of possession by a literal spirit.  But you interpret it as a literal possession?  Does that happen in Middle Earth?

Comment: @Nerrolken - on the evidence of the first quote I gave that is a fair interpretation, but the second quote I gave establishes that Carcharoth could speak, so we have to assume that it was a literal spirit.  This seems to be the general case for werewolves; e.g "Yet at length Draugluin escaped, and fleeing back into the tower he died before Saurons feet; and as he died he told his master: 'Huan is there!'"

Comment: Also see the Lay of Leithian: "Fierce hunger-haunted packs he had that in wolvish form and flesh were clad, **but demon spirits dire did hold**".

Answer (score 33):

Their origin is not entirely known.

This [source](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Origins_of_Dragons) states:

> Tolkien clearly wrote that dragons were bred by Morgoth but no one is
>   sure how. Some belief that dragons are embodied Maiar, others believe
>   they are simply beasts who were trained by Morgoth to speak and to
>   think, still others suggest they are "sparks" of Morgoth himself,
>   another theory is that dragons are crossbred from balrogs and other
>   beasts

The dragons are known to be immortal, powerful, intelligent, but also greedy.

Another [theory](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Origins_of_Dragons) about their origin states:

> The theory that Dragons were simply beasts perhaps physically enhanced
>   by Morgoth, such as corrupted eagles is a very popular theory.

There are two types of dragons:

- [Cold-drakes](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Cold-drakes)
- [Fire-drakes](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Fire-drakes) (Urulóki)

There is also another third type, Long-worms, without wings.

Cold-drakes were used to create Fire-drakes, but [origin](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Cold-drakes) of the Cold-drakes is not known:

> Tolkien gives no hint to the history of the cold-drakes after this
>   time period. They may have, however, been animals created by Yavanna
>   (and therefore the first dragons) that were then used by Morgoth to
>   breed the much stronger and more wicked Uruloki.

Smaug being one of the [fire-drakes](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Fire-drakes):

> Tolkien confirmed in a letter that Smaug was the last of his kind (The
>   last of the great Fire Drakes of Middle Earth...

By this statement we can conclude that Smaug was bred by Morgoth.

But, there is something else (from [Fire-drakes](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Fire-drakes)):

> All the famous dragons throughout the ages were fire-drakes (aka
>   Ancalagon, Glaurung, Smaug, etc.) although only some of them fought
>   for Morgoth

So not all of them fought for him, but all were enhanced by him (it seems).

Further explanation to Smaugs appearance in the Third Age, [Fire-drakes](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Fire-drakes):

> All Fire-drakes were thought to have been killed before the Second
>   Age, but Smaug the Golden survived and in the Third Age descended on
>   Erebor in TA 2770 and sacked the Lonely Mountain, at the time held by
>   Thrór, the Dwarven King under the Mountain.

Answer (score 6):

In the Silmarillion, Morgoth created the first dragon Glaurung. The first of the Urulóki (the Fire-drakes of Angband), he was much more powerful than what Smaug is shown to be. He could speak and understand tongues and control the mind of men. Glaurung is supposed to have sired the rest of his kin.

Though Glaurung is known as the Father of the Dragons, Ancalagon the Black was a winged dragon whereas Glaurung was wingless. According to wikipedia, Ancalagon was created by Sauron in the first age, so he is presumably not descended directly from Glaurung.

As to how Glaurung was created, there are many theories, one saying that they are corrupted eagles, one saying that they are Maiar in corporeal form. For a detailed discussion of this, [look at this excellent article](http://cogitemusaccurate.blogspot.com/).

Comment: Isn't it canon that no being other than Ilúvatar can create things? Orcs and goblins came from Morgoth's capture and subsequent torture and corruption of Elves. If dragons came from Morgoth, then what did he use to make them?

Comment: Yawus, that is not canon. Dwarves were created by Aule and animals and plants were created by Yavanna, for example.

Comment: Dwarves were given shape by Aule, true, but it was [Iluvatar who gave them consciousness](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Eru_Il%C3%BAvatar). Well, at least according to the wiki (which is hardly primary source). It (the wiki) also didn't say anything about [animals being created by Yavanna](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Yavanna).

Comment: @Yawus "created" as in "corrupted" is often apparent in Tolkien. Think of orcs, which are mentioned as being created but are then postulated as being corrupted hobbits.

Comment: There's this quote - "As yet no flower had bloomed nor any bird had sung, for these things waited still their time in the bosom of Yavanna" - from the first chapter of The Silmarillion, which could be interpreted as Yavanna creating animals and plants. However, you could also interpret it (and I personally would) as them being created by Iluvatar, but their forms were influenced by Yavanna.

Comment: @Steam Elves or Men, you mean. Tolkien noted both as possibilities.

Comment: @jwenting I'm curious how orcs could be corrupted hobbits given so many differences. It's known that Elves are rather tall and very much like Men only that they were immortal (ageing wise) whereas Men weren't. Hobbits weren't very tall, were quiet and I'm not even sure if they were around when the Orcs were first created in the first place. Or I misunderstand you?

Comment: @Pryftan from the background lore (history of ME etc.) it shows that the Orcs were likely bred from the same ancestral line that also yielded the hobbits. This happened a long, long time ago though. Case of parallel development.

Comment: @jwenting Which volume(s)? I have it all but I haven't read them all. Not because it's too dry just that I read other things too and also I have read some of them more than once over others - as well as UT, the Letters and numerous other things besides the normal things. Or is this maybe the first five, for the First Age? Of course the way I interpret it doesn't imply they're corrupted hobbits so much as they are somehow in the direct line much like we as humans all descend from Africa. But that doesn't mean we're all <insert trait> or whatever.