# What creatures were dragons made in mockery of?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, dragons

I've been wondering about this for years.  It seems like a pretty obvious question, so I'm surprised not to have found it addressed among the other Tolkien minutiae on this site.  Hopefully I haven't missed it, but anyway, here goes...

In Tolkien's Middle-Earth writings, Evil cannot create things, only twist and warp what already exists.  Thus, Orcs are twisted Elves, Trolls are twisted Ents, etc.  So then, what's the original source for Dragons?  They look pretty original to me!

The only template that seems even remotely possible is the Eagles, as they're both powerful fliers, but the connection seems very remote indeed.  Also, as twisted copies Orcs and Trolls are markedly inferior to Elves and Ents respectively, but I'm not aware of any text describing Dragons as inferior to Eagles.

Comment: Where does it say that trolls came from Ents?

Comment: Also, it could be that dragons are, or are derived from, primordial beings otherwise unknown to Arda.  Creatures like [Ungoliant](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Ungoliant) have no known origin, and Shelob was descended from her.  It's just speculation, but it could be that dragons have a similar lineage.

Comment: @Nerrolken Treebeard says it in *The Two Towers* "But Trolls are only counterfeits, made by the Enemy in the Great Darkness, in mockery of Ents". Tolkien discusses this idea in Letter 153, and neither entirely confirms or denies it

Comment: @JasonBaker Interesting!  I missed that entirely...  Although I suppose "made it mockery of" doesn't necessarily mean "made from."  It's a much bigger leap from Ent to Troll than from Elf to Orc, genealogically speaking...

Comment: @Nerrolken Well, yes. You should take a look at Letter 153; Tolkien goes into more detail, and the closest thing to a definitive statement is "the real world isn't always consistent, why does my fictional one have to be?"

Comment: It is not evil that cannot create sentient life. No one except Eru can.

Answer (score 1):

The first dragons were flightless at any rate. Glaurung, the father of all dragons, was a wingless fire-wyrm.

[image: Glaurung] 
Unfortunately, I fear this question will be removed by its likeness to [Where did dragons come from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36323/where-did-dragons-come-from)
wherein it is also described that the original breeding stock of dragons is unknown.